# AP and "radar detection" channels

Tags: wireless-networking

On my AP I have those channels available:

```
* 5200 MHz [40] (18.0 dBm)
* 5220 MHz [44] (18.0 dBm)
* 5240 MHz [48] (18.0 dBm)
* 5260 MHz [52] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5280 MHz [56] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5300 MHz [60] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5320 MHz [64] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5500 MHz [100] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5520 MHz [104] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5540 MHz [108] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5560 MHz [112] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5580 MHz [116] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5600 MHz [120] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5620 MHz [124] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5640 MHz [128] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5660 MHz [132] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5680 MHz [136] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5700 MHz [140] (18.0 dBm) (radar detection)
* 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
* 5745 MHz [149] (18.0 dBm)
* 5765 MHz [153] (18.0 dBm)
* 5785 MHz [157] (18.0 dBm)
* 5805 MHz [161] (18.0 dBm)
* 5825 MHz [165] (18.0 dBm)
* 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
* 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
* 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
```

The channels "disabled" are of course unavailable.

The channels 52, 56, 100 and 104 and other are marked with “radar detection.”

What does it mean "radar detection"? Is legal to use those channels?

Actually I use 40.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's perfectly legal to use them.

Those channels overlap with frequencies that were once used by certain kinds of radar systems, and some legacy radar installations may still use those frequencies.

In order to allow Wi-Fi to use those frequencies and not cause problems for old radar sites, Wi-Fi equipment must do "radar detection", also known as "Dynamic Frequency Selection" (DFS), when attempting to use those channels.

If radar-like energy pulses are detected on those channels, your equipment will automatically switch to another channel chosen at random.

Some equipment will not allow you to manually set it to use these channels, so they don't have to explain all this if your equipment ended up on a different channel than the one you'd set it to (because a radar energy pulse had forced it to abandon the set channel and pick a new one at random).

Comment: What is "legacy" about C-band weather radar systems? I'm certainly not an expert, but I know for sure that there's lots of such radar sites around me (western/central Europe). I would even guess that most weather radars here are C-band. Are they all outdated?

Comment: The following paper seems to confirm my suspicions (it's from 2015, so have things changed a lot since then?): [Saltikoff et al., The Threat to Weather Radars by Wireless Technology](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283760070_The_Threat_to_Weather_Radars_by_Wireless_Technology). Check out Figure 4 in particular.

Answer (score 0):

It might, or might not, be legal to use those channels in your (unstated) jurisdiction.

Using them is probably fine, or might possibly get you an unannounced visit from some serious gentlemen particularly if you're anywhere near an airfield etc.

That's why APs from reputable manufacturers are tailored for a specific country.

Comment: Normally APs have a configuration option for the region they are operated in. And built-in data whhich channels are allowed.